# When I double click on a word in the textbox I want to get that word("text") in a C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, visual-studio-2013

I am making a C# wpf application with Visual Studio 2013. I have a multilined text box with some sentences. When I double click on a word in the textbox I want to get that word("text").

How can I achieve this ?

[image]

This is the code I wrote for double click event. It gives me an empty String.

```
private void textBoxResult_PreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(textBoxResult.SelectedText);
    }
```

Comment: please clarify. do you want to find word "text" in the Text of the TextBox? or you want to retrieve the value of Text? or you want to retrieve the word which is double clicked?

Comment: I want to retrieve the value of the word which is double clicked in the textbox.

Comment: @pushpraj added a picture :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will get the text from the `SelectedText` property

xaml

```
    <TextBox Text="1. (n.) One who numbers." 
             MouseDoubleClick="TextBox_MouseDoubleClick"/
             AcceptsReturn="True" >
```

code behind handler

```
    private void TextBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
        String doubleClickedWord = tb.SelectedText;
    }
```

idea behind is that when you double click a word it gets selected and can be retrieved from `SelectedText` property

Comment: does this answer the question `When I double click on a word in the textbox I want to get that word("text")` ?

Comment: The answer is incomplete, however the property will yeld that info

Comment: Yep it is not working with the double clicked event :(

Comment: Then show the code you have written in the DoubleClick event because it should work.